# How can I remove a virtual machine from a network (vSwitch) in vSphere?

Tags: networking, vmware

The question title really says it all -- the documentation describes how to remove network cards (i.e. pulling the network adapter out of the VM), but not removing a VM from an existing network.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to *remove* VMs from a network, but you can certainly switch which network they are associated with.  (One way you could remove a VM from the network, is, well, remove the network card ;))

Steps are given under vSphere ESXi 4.1

1. Create a new network under Configuration -> Network.  You can keep all the default settings, but give it a good name.
2. Go into the VM settings.
3. Select the network adapter.
4. Switch networks under Network Label (this is the name you gave your new network).